# Convert dev environment from C/VI/Make to VCC

Tags: winapi

I have a rather large C program I wrote over several years that started as a simple Win32 GUI.  I used vi, nmake and microsoft's CL command line compiler as my build environment.  It is a reasonably complex GUI with several running threads, network servers a COM port interface, several dialog boxes etc...  I hand-built each item in the GUI and my makefile just builds them with the resource compiler (RC) prior to final linkage. Very tedious to change or update especially if it touches the GUI.

Anyway, the program lives on, but I'd really like to transition over to visual studio, and recreate the GUI using up-to-date tools.  I don't want to use .NET, and I don't need C++, but I'm assuming I'm stuck with it if I do this (am I?).
Anyone have any suggestions on how to begin this without a lot of C-to-C++ rewriting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most C can be ported to C++ with little more than renaming the file extension from .c to .cpp.  You get the benefits of C++ (stronger type checking, etc) but you can still write straight C.

But if you don't want to make that change, you can still use Visual Studio.  Just create a new C++ project (File/New/From Existing Code) and point it at your existing C files.  Visual Studio will happily compile and link your .c and .rc files without forcing you to use C++.

Comment: Hmmm... never thought to just try that.  What I really want (more than the C/C++ thing) is the ability to visually modify the GUI and then also debug it (with breakpoints, etc...)  I'll report back on how that works out.  Thanks

Comment: The GUI editor should work fine.  It doesn't care about C vs. C++ at all.

Comment: Finally had a chance to try this...  Good stuff!  Didn't realize you could do a "New/From Existing Code".  Thanks much.